# Generic FetchDictionary method for petapoco

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, petapoco

PetaPoco has this method :

```
public List<T> Fetch<T>(string sql, params object[] args) 
    {
        return Query<T>(sql, args).ToList();
    }
```

I want to create a method like this :

```
        public Dictionary<Guid, T> FetchDict<T>(string sql, params object[] args)
    {
//What goes here ?
        return Query<T>(sql, args).ToDictionary(x => ???, x => x);
    }
```

In the stub above, it should use reflection & use the PrimaryKey attribute and set that field as key. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :

```
public Dictionary<K, T> FetchDict<K,T>(string sql, params object[] args)
    {   
        Type typ = typeof(T);
        var primKey = TableInfo.FromPoco(typ).PrimaryKey;
        var prop = typ.GetProperty(primKey);
        return Query<T>(sql, args).ToDictionary(x => (K)prop.GetValue(x), x => x);
    }
```